# crystal reports - formula field conditional statement on what records to sum

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

**crystal reports formula field**
Good day,
I am making a sales report on Crystal Report - VS2010 c#

I have this view in MS SQL

vSales

```
OrderNo

OrderDate

Amount

PaymentType
```

Payment type can either be Cash or Check
I performed select all because I need both in the same report

so how do I get the sum of Amount where PaymentType is equal to cash?

I used Sum for my total Amount, both check and cash, in the formula workshop

```
Sum ({vDailySales.Amount})
```

I can't modify my SELECT statement because I need all the record with cash & check payment

Answer (score 5):

Create two formulas - CashAmount and CheckAmount, for example second one:

```
if {vDailySales.PaymentType}="cheque" 
then {vDailySales.Amount}
else 0
```

On report, use aggregates of said formulas - like Sum({@CashAmount}).

Comment: +1 Not sure why I forgot to mention this technique.  A sum of this field can also be used in the header section (which a running-total field can not).  Moreover, if you change this formula to if {vDailySales.PaymentType}="cheque" then {vDailySales.Amount} (removing the else portion of the formula), you can easily calculate the average using a Summary-field.  The null values, created by the missing else section, will be excluded from the calculation.

Comment: this works.  why can't I combine the two functions as one and reduce the amount of coding

Comment: @GoldenLion You need two different totals displayed on report - you can't return two values from single formula. What you have against coding, by the way? :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I would use; depending on what output I wanted.

The first way, and the simplest would be group on the payment type.  Then create a sum in the footer of the group.  You can use the "Running Total" tool or use the code below.

```
SUM({vDailySales.Amount}, {vDailySales.PaymentType})
```

This will show a result for each of the payment types, so in your case twice, once for cash and once for cheque.

I think through here you can use formulas in the "Evaluate" section of running total; where you would use a true/false statement for what you wanted to show.  The statement for "cash" for example would be:

```
if {vDailySales.PaymentType}="Cash" then true else false
```

The other method, which would be simpler if you wanted a grand total would be to use a conditional sum.

Define the variables in the header:

```
SHARED numbervar sumcash;
SHARED numbervar sumcheque;
sumcheque:=0;
sumcash:=0;
```

Then for each line in the report; add a field to conditionally sum the amounts; using a formula like:

```
SHARED numbervar sumcash;
SHARED numbervar sumcheque;

if {vDailySales.PaymentType}="cheque" then
     sumcheque = sumcheque + {vDailySales.Amount};
else
     sumcash = sumcash + {vDailySales.Amount};
```

Then at the bottom of the report, make a formula to display each of the variables seperately.

Answer (score 3):

A third option is to use a running-total field.  Because of how they are calculated, they need to be in a footer section.

To create one, follow these steps:

1. select the {vDailySales.Amount} field on the canvas, right click, then select Insert, Running Total...
2. Set the Running Total Name field as appropriate, perhaps 'Sum of Cash'.
3. Ensure that the Type of Summary is 'sum'.
4. Select the 'Use a formula' option, click the conditional-formula button, then enter the following as the formula's text:
   {vDailySales.PaymentType}="Cash"
5. Select 'Never' for the Reset option or 'On change of group' (selecting the appropriate group) if this RT field will tally an amount by group.
6. Place field in the Report Footer section.

Repeat the process for a second running-total field that will summarize cheques (change step 4 to reference "Cheque" instead of "Cash".